Does a parenthesized "and" clause make a subject plural?
Which of the following is correct:
"Wheat (and thus wheat products, such as bread) is a good source of fibre."
or
"Wheat (and thus wheat products, such as bread) are good sources of fibre."
In other words, do you take parenthesized clauses into account when determining whether a subject is singular or plural?
The question is specifically about parenthesized clauses, not about the clauses that play the same role but are only separated by commas.

Don't write it: say it. Now you know the answer.

This question is about the cases in which the relevant words are in parentheses; the other question is about the cases in which they are separated by commas. One may reasonably wonder whether these two kinds of cases should be handled the same way. If they should, that needs to be said explicitly and posted as an answer to this question, rather than just implied by closing it as a duplicate of the other one.

@jsw29 Why would written punctuation change the answer found in the spoken language? Isn't speech primary and writing secondary?

@tchrist I'm actually confused now. After your first comment, I figured the answer was "are", because that clearly sounded better to me when spoken. But the duplicate question recommends "is" in a similar situation, "The team captain, as well as his players, is anxious."

@tchrist, because there is (or, at least, many people believe that there is) a rule that what is in parentheses (which have no unambiguous spoken counterpart) should never affect the grammatical structure of what's outside them (i.e. that what is outside the parentheses must be written so that it would be grammatically OK if the parenthetical clause were deleted). If one follows that rule, one will not regard it as dispositive how it all sounds when uttered. I understand that you think that it is dispositive, but that is something that you need to argue for; it cannot just be assumed.

Related: Changing plurality in parentheses. The most highly upvoted answer to that question argues that all such sentences ought to be rewritten so as to avoid the problem; it seems to imply that one should never attempt to say what the OP of this question wants to say, in either its plural or singular version.

The mere fact that you have placed those words inside parentheses does not make them syntactically parenthetic. .  Your parentheses are spurious.  Analyze the sentence based on its clauses, not on its punctuation.

Surprisingly few usage guides (among the two dozen or so that I consulted) directly address this question—and those that do are not unanimous in the advice they offer.
Bryan Garner, Garner's American Usage, third edition (2009) includes this assessment in a longer entry headed "Parentheses":

The first of those uses [to "indicate interpolations and remarks by the writer of the text"] comes into play most frequently. The main test for whether a parenthetical construction works is whether the rest of the sentence makes sense without it. That's because words contained within parentheses do not affect the syntax of the rest of the sentence. E.g.: "We must determine whether each (or both) children are entitled to tickets." The writer of that sentence could have avoided this error (each children are) by reading the sentence without the parenthetical phrase.

If, as Gartner asserts, the syntax of a sentence should remain unaffected by removal of the parenthetical phrase, it seems clear that "Wheat (and thus wheat products, such as bread) is a good source of fibre" is correct and "Wheat (and thus wheat products, such as bread) are good sources of fibre" is incorrect.
Nevertheless, I wish that Garner had provided a more thorough critique of his own example. Are we to suppose that, since "We must determine whether each child is entitled to [a] ticket" is syntactically sound, the sentence with parenthetical in place should read as "We must determine whether each (or both) child is entitled to a ticket"? That sentence seems so untenably awful that I can't imagine Garner would approve of using it. To repair the original sentence, the writer would do better to abandon the parentheses altogether and rephrase the sentence in a less distracting way. For example: "We must determine whether each child is entitled to a ticket or whether both are."
Applying much the same reasoning that Garner uses, The American Heritage Guide to Contemporary Usage and Style (2005) offers this guideline in its discussion of parentheses:

A sentence containing material in parentheses is grammatical only if it remains grammatical when the parenthetical element is removed. For example, it is incorrect to write The draft bill was reviewed by the secretary of the interior (not to mention by the President's chief of staff) and they approved it, since the plural pronoun they would require that the President's chief of staff serve as part of the antecedent. Similarly one cannot write He gave her a Bible (and later a rosary), which were found by her bedside when she died, where part of the subject of the plural verb were would have to be drawn from the material in parentheses.

The two examples here are fairly easy to bring into compliance with the book's guideline by removing the parentheses marks and doing some minor rewording or repunctuation: "The draft bill was reviewed by the secretary of the interior and the President's chief of staff, and they approved it," and "He gave her a Bible and, later, a rosary, which were found by her bedside when she died."
Where did the rule enunciated by Garner and American Heritage come from? I think that it follows from an application of a more general notion of parenthesis as (to quote Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary [2003]) "an amplifying or explanatory word, phrase, or sentence inserted in a passage from which it is usu. set off by punctuation." The rule thus treats a parenthesis (or parenthetical expression) as supplemental—and therefore syntactically extraneous—to the core sentence in which it appears.
Words Into Type, third edition (1974) includes a more general discussion of the underlying idea here:

The number of the subject and verb is not affected by intervening words introduced by with, together with, including, as well as, no less than, plus, and similar expressions.

The farmer's happiness as well as his profits arises from being a part of a neighborhood instead of being merely a resident in it.
The load of ore, together with the consignment of pig iron, was delivered on time.
The rhyming no less than the meter of the poem is amateurish.
All living things, and therefore protoplasm, are composed of these substances.
Broth does not ferment or decay if the air, and consequently germs in the air, is excluded.

Writers sometimes use these phrases where, because the thought is plural, a simple and would be better. Copy editors should think of this if they come upon one og these phrases followed by a plural verb when the grammatical subject is singular.

Poor: Heart disease, together with cancer, kidney diseases, and apoplexy are almost entirely diseases of middle life and older periods.
Better: Heart disease, cancer, kidney diseases, and apoplexy are...
Poor: This zygote, with the hyphae that develop from it, probably represent the diploid stage.
Better: This zygote and the hyphae that develop from it represent...


Conspicuously contrary to the guidelines proposed by these authorities is the advice in Benjamin Dreyer, Dreyer's English: An Utterly Correct Guide to Clarity and Style (2019):

This is correct:

Remind me again why I care what this feckless nonentity (and her eerie husband) think about anything.

This is not correct:

Remind me again why I care what this feckless nonentity (and her eerie husband) thinks about anything.

An "and" is an "and," and the use of parentheses(or commas or dashes) to break up a plural subject for whatever reason does not negate the pluralness of the subject. Now, if instead of writing "and," I'd written "to say nothing of," "as well as," or "not to mention." then I'd have made me a singular subject:

Remind me again why I care what this feckless nonentity (to say nothing of her eerie husband) thinks about anything.


Dreyer is the copy chief (that is, head of the copy editing department) at Random House. His take on the question seems to start with the idea that punctuation marks are subordinate (or indeed extraneous) to syntax. According to this view, adding commas or dashes or parentheses to a sentence that contains a relevant "and" has no effect on the grammatical number of the subject.
In contrast, Garner and American Heritage and Words into Type seem to imagine a baseline sentence that has a settled syntax but has then been amplified by a parenthetical interpolation that may or may not include clarifying punctuation but that in any case does not alter the grammatical number of the baseline sentence's subject just because the additional wording begins with "and" or "or."
These are irreconcilable positions, it seems to me.
My own view is that it is a mistake to use punctuation that raises issues of visual consistency (or inconsistency), as the example in the posted question does. That's because I think that the central purpose of punctuation is to guide readers through a sentence as surefootedly yet unobtrusively as possible. If a reader is left staring at a sentence because the number of the subject and the number of the verb seem oddly mismatched, then either the punctuation that the writer included isn't helping or the writer fell into the trap of being correct (according to the writer's understanding of the writer's preferred rule) instead of idiomatically normal.
If I were editing the example sentence, I would change "thus" to "by extension" and dump the parentheses:

Wheat and, by extension, wheat products such as bread are good sources of fibre.

As you can see, treating "wheat" and "wheat products" as separate entities provides a logical basis for referring to them as "sources" rather than "a source" later in the sentence. I prefer "by extension" to "thus" because the intended relationship between "wheat" and "wheat products" is easier to infer from it.

Thank you for this well-researched answer!

It seems to me that the position of Words into Type, which is about coma-separated clauses, raises issues that stand to the side of the straightforward conflict between the two positions about parentheses (brackets). One may reasonably think that commas (the vaguest punctuation mark or all) do not provide the same sort of syntactic insulation that parentheses do, and that therefore sort-of-parenthetical clauses that are merely comma-separated should not be treated the same way as those that are actually enclosed in parentheses.

@jsw29: Words into Type certainly applies a broad brush to the topic. However, I can't read the last example from its first set of examples ("Broth does not ferment or decay if the air, and consequently germs in the air, is excluded") as anything other than an endorsement of the Garner/American Heritage view of the syntactical relationship between what they seem to consider the essential base of a sentence and any attached parentheticals—even though the parenthetical in this case is set off with commas, which are (as you say) relatively weak and potentially ambiguous punctuation marks.

@SvenYargs, oh, yes, it is virtually certain that somebody who handles comma-separated 'parentheticals' that way, will handle genuine parentheticals the same way, but I don't think that there is an implications in the other direction. One may want to write 'Wheat (and thus wheat products, such as bread) is . . .', but '"Wheat, and thus wheat products, such as bread, are . . .'. In other words, one may argue that the punctuation plays the crucial role here, rather than the logical relationship of the clause to the rest of the sentence (which seems to be the Words into Type position).
